# No connection string named "thenameofmyconnection" could be found in the application config file

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure

I am working with entity framework and azure, I got a WCF in a web role which uses methods from the project with entity framework..it seems that I am placing the connection string on the wrong file or that I am defining it wrongly.. it is as follows :

```
<connectionStrings>
  <!-- Windows Azure SQL Database Connection String -->

  <add name="AMTEntitiesContainer" 
   connectionString="here goes my connection string" 
   providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

</connectionStrings>
```

This is inside my app.config file in my entities library project..should it go to into the config of my webrole? or should it go into my WCF service ?

Comment: app.config file should be located in the same directory as the executable which is using it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The connection string should be in the web.config of the WCF service. The EntityFramework project will be executed in-process. The WCF service is the process running.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494.aspx) could be also helpful to understand these things.

I'm sorry for the post, I can not write comments yet.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the WebService that interact with Azure, you need to move this into its Web.config. If it's the application you have another problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this,
Simply because I was creating my model incorrectly. 
I was incorrectly doing:

`var model = new ModelName;`

Instead of correctly doing:

`var model = ModelName.Create();`

So this error may be thrown for a simple reason like that